# How to access the localhost ruby on rails server in internet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost, railsinstaller

I m using `railsinstaller`

```
http://localhost:3000/wage
```

Next page

```
http://localhost:3000/wage/results?hours=23
```

I try to access

```
myip:3000/wage
```

But it shows `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

I get the myip from `ipconfig-->ipv4`

Is the url wrong or configuration problem?

Comment: How do you start `rails s`? or `rails -s -b 0.0.0.0` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've started well, but for local LAN only.

1. For **intranet** only, you can use your LAN ip.
   Test it from another local machine (same LAN). Hope it works.

If your firewall and machine settings allow you to view on intranet, than go to next step:

2. **For internet**, 
   first make sure you have your public internet address, by visiting `http://api.ipify.org/` > you will see your public IP address. Use it to access your website `http://<public_address>:3000/`

If it works on intranet, but not on internet, you need to open the port 3000 in your router and forward it to your local machine. (If you have no access to router settings, ask your administrator to help you with this).

Give me more details for a more complete solution.
What OS are you using?

**EDIT:**

For Windows10 you have to make sure to open the port **3000** in your firewall.

- Navigate to Control Panel, System and Security and Windows Firewall.
- Select Advanced settings and highlight Inbound Rules in the left pane.
- Right click Inbound Rules and select New Rule.
- Add the port you need to open and click Next.
- Add the protocol (TCP or UDP) and the port number into the next window and click Next.
- On the "Profile" step select all 3 (Domain, Private, Public)
- Select Allow the connection in the next window and hit Next.
- Select the network type as you see fit and click Next.
- Name the rule something meaningful (like: Allow incoming connections on port 3000) and click Finish.

To change the default 3000 port use:

`rails server -p 8080` to change port

`rails server -b 0.0.0.0` to bind 0.0.0.0 address

**UPDATE:**

When server starts will output to the console, the address:port it listens. example:
`Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000` as a development server it can be set to listen on localhost requests only.

To override that settings use:

`rails server -p <3030> -b 0.0.0.0` this will listen to all incoming connections on port 3030

For more details on the `-p`, and `-b` consult the help:

```
$ rails server -h
Usage: rails server [mongrel, thin etc] [options]
    -p, --port=port                  Runs Rails on the specified port.
                                    Default: 3000
    -b, --binding=IP                 Binds Rails to the specified IP.
                                    Default: localhost
    -c, --config=file                Uses a custom rackup configuration.
    -d, --daemon                     Runs server as a Daemon.
    -e, --environment=name           Specifies the environment to run this server under (test/development/production).
                                    Default: development
    -P, --pid=pid                    Specifies the PID file.
                                    Default: tmp/pids/server.pid
    -C, --[no-]dev-caching           Specifies whether to perform caching in development.
                                    true or false

    -h, --help                       Shows this help message.
```

Comment: `http://api.ipify.org/` this website shows the ip that I found in ipconfig

Comment: Do you have a direct internet connection or through a router?

Comment: direct internet connection . home internet. still not function

Comment: @Monchhichi please make sure you have the port 3000 opened. Follow the steps here: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/faq/id-3114787/open-firewall-ports-windows.html

Comment: xampp opens the ports for you at installationtime. Also make sure that you're antivirus is not having separate firewall rulles.

Comment: Still doesn't work ,even I close the window firewall. Maybe I should change the default port of railsinstaller as 3030 .I tried 3030 and worked when I use XMAPP .Do you know how to change ?

Comment: have you used `rails server -p 3030` or `rails -s -p 3030` to change port?

Comment: I shut down the anti-virus and try `rails server -p 9898` .http://localhost:9898/wage this work .But ip:9898/wage still doesnt work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135447/discussion-between-codrut-tg-and-monchhichi).